# Access OnStar Wires on 2012 Equinox

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, equinox

I've got a 2012 Equinox that I want to attach an inviscord to the Onstar wires, but I am not sure how to access the wires.  There is a wide black plastic cover where the rear view mirror attaches to the vehicle.  I believe this cover is holding the wiring along with the sensors for forward collision detection and lane departure detection.  As I don't want to break anything I was hoping to get some instruction to take this apart.